# How to conver a single array to multidimention array from chekboxes

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array like this from checkboxes html:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
)
```

How to make this array like this

```
Array (
  array(
     'ID_REQUEST' => 1 //push new element (constant)
     'ID_TIPE' => 1 // this is from first elemnt of array below
  ),   
  array(
     'ID_REQUEST' => 1 //push new element (constant)
     'ID_TIPE' => 2 // this is from second elemnt of array below
  ),   

)
```

Thanks before.

Comment: what are `ID_REQUEST` and `ID_TIPE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$new_array= array();
for($i=0;$i<count($first_array);$i++)
{
    $newdata =  array ('ID_REQUEST' => 'constant1',
    'ID_TIPE' => $first_array[$i]
);
    array_push($new_array[$i],$newdata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$new_arr =array();
foreach($your_array as $k=>$v){
    $temp['ID_REQUEST'] = 1;
    $temp['id_type'] = $v;
    array_push($new_arr,$temp);
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The shortest one:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$new_arr = array_map(function($v){ return ['ID_REQUEST' => 1, 'ID_TIPE' => $v]; }, $arr);
```